# Create matrix using loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Here I have a list of numbers (900 numerical values) denoted as d1-1, d1-2, d1-3.....d1-30, d2-1, d2-2, d2-3........d30-30. I want to create a matrix (900x900) which is organized as the below picture. Someone suggested to me that I should use the do loop or while loop. Can you guys help me with this? d1-2 has a magnitude the same as d2-1 but with negative sign.

[image: Here is the matrix I want to create]

Comment: Surely, Vector multiplication is enough?

Comment: I don't recommend `Subscript`s as they cause problems when using `Set`, `Information`, etc. Try using brackets instead. E.g. `d[1, 1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbolic evaluation (if you only need some of the elements of the matrix, use this).

```
mat[row_, col_] := 
 d[Ceiling[row/30], Ceiling[col/30]] d[Mod[row, 30, 1], Mod[col, 30, 1]]
```

For instance:

```
mat[50, 80]
(* d[2, 3] d[20, 20] *)
```

If you want the actual matrix, just do:

```
matrix = Array[mat, {900, 900}]
```

**EDIT:** If you must use a loop (which is slower), then try this:

```
matrix = Table[d[Ceiling[row/30], Ceiling[col/30]] d[Mod[row,
   30, 1], Mod[col, 30, 1]], {row, 900}, {col, 900}]
```

Comment: thank you, actually need a numerical matrix rather than symbolic matrix like this. I have the list of all the value for d[1,2], d[1,3]......up to d[30-30] (which is 900 numerical number). How can I assign those number to d[1,1], d[1,2].....in the above code?

Comment: If your list is level 2 (`{{d[1, 1], ... d[1, 30]}, {d[2, 1], ... d[2, 30]}, ... {d[30, 1], ... d[30, 30]}}`) then you could do `Evaluate[Array[d, {30, 30}]] = (* your list *)`. If your list is level 1 (`{d[1, 1], d[1, 2], ... d[30, 30]}`), then try `Evaluate[Flatten@Array[d, {30, 30}]] = (* your list *)`.

Comment: For the numerical matrix, just run the third code I posted (`matrix = Array[mat, {900, 900}]`).

Answer (score 5):

Something like that?

The initial matrix (general case):

```
mat = Array[d, {30, 30}]; mat // MatrixForm
```

Gives:
[image]

Then:

```
vec = Flatten[mat]; {vec} // MatrixForm
```

And finally:

```
bigmat = Transpose[{vec}].{vec};
```

Checking:

```
bigmat[[1]]

bigmat[[;; , 1]]

Diagonal[bigmat]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, however if you try to check bigmat[[1,2]] is give d[1,1]*d[1,2]=bigmat[[2,1]]. However as I said, d[1,2]=-d[2,1], do you have any idea how to fix it. 

Furthermore I have the list of all the value for d[1,2], d[1,3]......up to d[30-30] (which is 900 numerical number). How can I assign those number to d[1,1], d[1,2].....in the above code?

Comment: @Quang Phan. The input example I gave was the generic case, but you can always put d[j,i]=-d[i,j] in the example. Anyway, your own list of data (assuming it is a one dimension list of 900 elements) is just the intermediate "vec" entity I used, so I guess you just use Transpose[{vec}].{vec} to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `For[]` loop. What you need is `KroneckerProduct[]`:

```
KroneckerProduct[Array[d, {30, 30}], Array[d, {30, 30}]]
```